# Which method should I use to extract the specified data from a text?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, text, replace

I am trying to extract CSRF code from the text.

For example this is my text called `csrf`:

```
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)

        MarketManager.Cart.CartTotal = 0;        
        MarketManager.csrfCode = sd9192djsidhd72jSKkjS799;
        MarketManager.UserID = 22216;

                console.log(MarketWebSockets not loaded.);

    });
```

I need this `sd9192djsidhd72jSKkjS799` to be extracted.
I already used `csrf = csrf.replace(/"/g, '');` to remove quotation marks but I can't figure out how to use this method to get rid of other unnecessary information. Should I use another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for 'csrfCode = ', then search from there to ';'; the code is the stuff in between.

The methods you'll need are String's `.indexOf(needle)` as well as `.indexOf(needle, fromIndex)`, and to extract the string, some basic maths and `.substring(from, to)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest your simplest option is to use a regular expression. This performs well and is simple to use:

```
// Text to be searched
var csrf = `     (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)

    MarketManager.Cart.CartTotal = 0;        
    MarketManager.csrfCode = sd9192djsidhd72jSKkjS799;
    MarketManager.UserID = 22216;

            console.log(MarketWebSockets not loaded.);
        ;

});`

// regular expression to find "csrfCode = " and capture
// the alphanumeric string following it
var re = /csrfCode = (\w*)/s ;

// apply the regular expression
var result = re.exec( csrf );

// check and report the result
if( !result ){
  console.log( "No match found")}
else{
  // the captured string is stored in the result array
  console.log( "Match found: [" + result[1] + "]");
}
```